# How do you stop tomcat after changing the shutdown word in server.xml?

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml

Running tomcat-7.0.33 on CentOS. I have a security requirement to change the tomcat shutdown word in server.xml to a random string of characters, so I need to go from this:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to something like this

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="8GVsi4lMZTX6aOzorJYexiq8K7ZGxaZ">
```

However once that is in place, I cannot restart/stop tomcat via the init script (`/etc/init.d/tomcat stop`). When I attempt to, I get the following in my catalina.out:

```
Jul 22, 2014 8:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:499)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:453)
```

**Simple question**: how do I change the shutdown word in server.xml in such a way that I can use the init script just as I always would?
Or, if that does not have an answer, when I change the shutdown word in server.xml, how do I go about restarting/stopping the tomcat service?

Answer (score 0):

Shut down tomcat, then change it.

You can also do a simple unix kill command (this sends the INT signal, don't send the KILL signal) to the process. That will cleanly shut down tomcat as well.

Comment: The problem is not changing the word itself. The problem is after tomcat is started with the changed shutdown word in place, I cannot restart or stop tomcat using the init script.